# I'm unable to move to next screen by pressing native navigation tab until current screen taking finished load api data and render it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Here is my bottom tab in react native, when im in Home screen and hitting Scores tab its not loading until home screen loading data from API and rendering the screen.
How to move to next screen even we dont load complete api data when we hit other tab ?

```
 <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HOME"
        screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#A0D3A5',
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
            tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#41A64B',
                borderTopWidth: ScaleSize(1),
                paddingTop: ScaleSize(8),
                height: ScaleSize(70),
                borderBottomColor: "#41A64B",
                paddingBottom: 0,
            },
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
                fontSize: ScaleSize(12),
                fontFamily: "Inter",
                fontWeight: "500",
            },
        }}
    >
        <Tab.Screen
            name="HOME"
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                    <Box
                        borderBottomColor={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#41A64B"}
                        borderBottomWidth={3}
                        width="100%"
                        alignItems="center"
                        color={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#A0D3A5"}
                        height={8}
                    >
                        <Text
                            fontSize={ScaleSize(11)}
                            fontFamily="Inter"
                            fontWeight="500"
                            paddingBottom={ScaleSize(2)}
                            color={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#A0D3A5"}

                        >HOME</Text>
                    </Box>
                ),
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (

                    <TabIcon source={
                        focused
                            ? HomeDarkIcon
                            : HomeIcon
                    }

                    />

                ),

            }}

            listeners={homeTabBarListeners}
            component={HomeStack}
        >


        </Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen
            name="SCORES"
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                    <Box
                        borderBottomColor={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#41A64B"}
                        borderBottomWidth={3}
                        width="100%"
                        alignItems="center"
                        color={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#A0D3A5"}
                        height={8}
                    >
                        <Text
                            fontSize={ScaleSize(11)}
                            fontFamily="Inter"
                            fontWeight="500"
                            paddingBottom={ScaleSize(2)}
                            color={focused ? "#ffffff" : "#A0D3A5"}

                        >SCORES</Text>
                    </Box>
                ),
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                    <TabIcon source={
                        focused
                            ? ScoreDarkactive
                            : ScoreIcon
                    } />
                ),
            }}
            listeners={scoreTabBarListeners}
            component={ScoreBoardStack}
        >
        </Tab.Screen>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Expected result it i need to move to next tab when clicked, even if the existing screen didn't finish the api loading and rendering the screen